# How we can use DirectorySecurity class for getting write access to a directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

How we can use `DirectorySecurity` class for getting write access to a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method call:

```
// Add the access control entry to the directory.
AddDirectorySecurity(DirectoryName, @"MYDOMAIN\MyAccount", FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow);
```

Method definition:

```
// Adds an ACL entry on the specified directory for the specified account.
    public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
    {
        // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

        // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
        // current security settings.
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

        // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                        Rights,
                                                        ControlType));

        // Set the new access settings.
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

    }
```

(Taken from MSDN)

Comment: should I change  @"MYDOMAIN\MyAccount" ?